# How to implement and deploy pluggable ESCC or VSCC policies in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I want to add some extra validation and endorsement logic in the currently existing VSCC and ESCC respectively. Is there any documentation on how I can edit and deploy my custom VSCC and ESCC to Hyperledger Fabric?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All system chaincodes, in particular VSCC and ESCC, should implement [`Chaincode`](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L28) interface:

```
// Chaincode interface must be implemented by all chaincodes. The fabric runs
// the transactions by calling these functions as specified.
type Chaincode interface {
    // Init is called during Instantiate transaction after the chaincode container
    // has been established for the first time, allowing the chaincode to
    // initialize its internal data
    Init(stub ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response

    // Invoke is called to update or query the ledger in a proposal transaction.
    // Updated state variables are not committed to the ledger until the
    // transaction is committed.
    Invoke(stub ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response
}
```

At the moment all system chaincodes statically compiled into peer code and listed at [importsysccs.go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/scc/importsysccs.go#L29) file. Additionally they have to be enabled at [`core.yaml`](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L377) file within chaincode section, for example:

```
chaincode:

    # system chaincodes whitelist. To add system chaincode "myscc" to the
    # whitelist, add "myscc: enable" to the list below, and register in
    # chaincode/importsysccs.go
    system:
        cscc: enable
        lscc: enable
        escc: enable
        vscc: enable
        qscc: enable
```

Next, then you instantiate your chaincode and would like to provide custom VSCC and ESCC you need to provide their names into LSCC. For example if you will use peer cli you can do it as following:

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o localhost:7050 -n myCC -v 1.0 -C mychannel -c '{"Args": ["init"]}' --vscc myVSCC --escc myESCC
```

Answer (score 2):

VSCC and ESCC are system chaincode, and the interface is exactly like chaincode, so look at the chaincode document or go to the [VSCC source code](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/release/core/scc/vscc). You can add your own validation system chaincode and associate it with your chaincodes.

System chaincode is built with the peer executable and doesn't go through the transactional install/instantiate process. It is loaded when the peer is started up, so it requires some registration in core/scc/importsysccs.go. Take a look at **systemChaincodes** variable, and you can see how others are registered.

Comment: Could you please tell where does this importsysccs.go file exists?

Comment: @KartikChauhan, the importsysccs.go is in the source tree https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.3/core/scc/importsysccs.go

Comment: @KartikChauhan, however, it's been changed quite a lot since I provided the answer above. There is a new mechanism to do system chaincode using Go plugin. Check the document here https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/systemchaincode.html

If you don't want to use Go plugin system chaincode, follow how `qscc` is implemented and registered. You may find `qscc` here https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/release-1.3/core/scc/qscc.